# Android Java Calendar alternative, with following feature

Tags: java, android, calendar

I need to start my calendar from Monday.
As per today date(07/aug/2012) is concerned, with first day as monday and minimal days in week as 1, java is providing me week of year as 33 while android 32, WHY?

So i require calendar alternative that has following feature.
Code that i am using:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(1);

out("For date : "+df.format(cal.getTime())+" Week = "+cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you really running the exact same code on both your dev system and the phone? What does `cal.getFirstDayOfWeek()` print on Android: `1` (Sunday) or `2` (Monday)? This might be affected by your phone's locale.

Comment: @PhilippReichart : Hi, i have checked at both it's giving 2

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.AUGUST , 7 )
         .get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR )
```

> 32

## Locale

Not sure of the direct answer to your Question, but likely to be differing `Locale` values in play. In `Calendar` the definition of a week varies by the locale.

But **this is moot**. You should be using the *java.time* classes that replaced `Calendar` class.

## java.time

`Calendar` is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes. For earlier Android, see the last bullets below.

You must define what you mean by week number. There are different ways to define a week and week number.

By default, the java.time classes use the standard [ISO 8601 definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date): Week # 1 has the first Thursday of the calendar year, and starts on Monday (as you asked for). So years have either 52 or 53 weeks. The first and last few days of the calendar year may land in the prior/following week-based year.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.AUGUST , 7 ) ;
```

Interrogate for the standard week number. You can ask for either of these [`TemporalField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html) objects: [`IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_BASED_YEAR) & [`IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR)

```
int weekOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
int yearOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
```

Dump to console using standard [ISO 8601 format of `YYYY-Www-D`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates).

```
String isoOutput = yearOfWeekBasedYear + "-W" + String.format("%02d", weekOfWeekBasedYear) + "-" + dayOfWeekNumber  ;
System.out.println( ld + " is ISO 8601 week: " + isoOutput ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/52wrLG).

> 2012-08-07 is ISO 8601 week: 2012-W32-2

By the way, if Android is ever able to run the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library, you’ll find its [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class useful.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).